# Using gitweb to grep filenames?

Tags: gitweb

The grep drop-down works great for finding file content, but is there some way to find a file by name or glob from gitweb? Something along the lines of `find . -iname` but the gitweb equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of.

The ["File Finder" introduced by GitHub](https://github.com/blog/793-introducing-the-file-finder) (hit <kbd>t</kbd> in a GitHub project page) is not yet implemented in gitweb.

Comment: Bummer. Maybe this is a good opportunity to exercise my old rusty perl chops and get it added.

Comment: @CaptainMurphy That would be great. 
[Jakub Narębski](http://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-narebski) maintains gitweb, and will be thrilled to get a contribution.

Comment: Well I submitted the patch to the mailing list, no response yet (3 days later).

Comment: Got no response whatsoever, even though I read all the patch submission rules twice and followed them very closely. I know it got there because it's in the mailing list archive. @VonC, do you have any advice for getting some traction?

Comment: @CaptainMurphy maybe give them time for 1.8.4 to be released? Or directly contact http://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-narebski: he might guide you.